# Need help on pine scripting. How to use Heikinashi candles in my script?

Tags: pine-script

**Requirement**: I want to create a cloud (area) from supertrend (10,7) and EMA 20 using Heikinashi candles in my indicator.

I however want to plot this indicator on normal candles but indicator should show me a cloud formation of heikinashi supertrend (10,7) and EMA 20. As soon as a normal candle touches that cloud i would like to see some price action and then act on it.

I am fairly new to coding, can anyone please help me with some coding logic please ?

Really appreciate any help provided on this.

Comment: This is not a well-formed question for stackoverflow.  It sounds like you're asking someone to write your code for you.  At least present an outline of what you are thinking how the code should work, and ask if you are on the right track.  Or if you don't have that ability yet, then perhaps go back and study coding some more (there are no short cuts).  Alternatively find a platform that can do what you want.  Also considering asking on Trading View which is where Pine-Script is used anyway.  I am trying to encourage you.  Show whatever efforts you have already made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request data from the Heikin Ashi chart. In order to do that, you need to create a ticker identifier.

You can do that with `ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)`.

Then use `request.security()` to request data from Heikin Ashi bars.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

[supertrend_ha, direction_ha] = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, ta.supertrend(3, 10))

plot(direction_ha < 0 ? supertrend_ha : na, "Up direction", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(direction_ha > 0 ? supertrend_ha : na, "Down direction", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)
```